# How can I pass multiple file extensions parameter in header?

Tags: php, file, download, header-files

I have files of different extensions, So how can I define multiple extensions in one header. for example

```
 header("Content-type: application/xml"); 
 header("Content-type: application/txt");
```

Is there any possibilities are there, to define in a single header something like this

```
 header("Content-type: application/xml txt");
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want in downloading any type of file you can just use `application/octet-stream.`

```
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
```

// for example this will download any type of file

```
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
 header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . basename($file) . '"');
 header('Expires: 0');
 header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
 header('Pragma: public');
 header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
 readfile($file);
```

Comment: Thank you, but defining multiple extensions in single header is possible or not?